# How to map this data to reach data property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to clean up the data received from firebase to view them in a FlatList. How can I clean my data to a simple array where I can iterate in FlatList?

EDIT! There are many other coins in my database that I want to pull into the FlatList. So the solution that I'm looking for is to view all these coins in my FlatList and then show their data such as price, market_cap etc.

My data is currently stored in a state and looks like this.

```
favoriteList data is: 
 Object {
  "bitcoin": Object {
    "-MahI1hCDr0CJ_1T_umy": Object {
      "data": Object {
        "ath": 54205,
        "ath_change_percentage": -40.72194,
        "ath_date": "2021-04-14T11:54:46.763Z",
        "atl": 51.3,
        "atl_change_percentage": 62536.71794,
        "atl_date": "2013-07-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "circulating_supply": 18719656,
        "current_price": 32164,
        "fully_diluted_valuation": 674764316483,
        "high_24h": 33004,
        "id": "bitcoin",
        "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
        "last_updated": "2021-05-27T10:07:02.525Z",
        "low_24h": 30652,
        "market_cap": 601493137412,
        "market_cap_change_24h": -15118857257.119507,
        "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": -2.45192,
        "market_cap_rank": 1,
        "max_supply": 21000000,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "price_change_24h": -641.85835686,
        "price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency": 0.25769270475453127,
        "price_change_percentage_24h": -1.95655,
        "price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency": -1.9565521832416402,
        "price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency": 4.978932125496787,
        "symbol": "btc",
        "total_supply": 21000000,
        "total_volume": 36947814578,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

The firebase structure is like this where the data above is fetched from:

[image: the firebase data]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My list is large and I can't add the firebase key for every iteration. Sorry, I should have been more clear with question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is interesting to see how programmers interpret questions. Or perhaps how beginners fail to articulate clearly what they want to achieve. Here is the answer:

```
  const formatData = (data) => {
    let arr = [];
    let test = Object.values(data).forEach((o) => {
      Object.values(o).forEach((a) =>
        Object.values(a).forEach((b) => arr.push(b))
      );
      setFormattedData(arr);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(favourite.bitcoin)[idx]` This line gives you the name of key at index `0` into object `favourite.bitcoin`.

So the variable `key` will be your firebase key.

```js
let favourite = {
  bitcoin: {
    "-MahI1hCDr0CJ_1T_umy": {
      data: {
        ath: 54205,
        ath_change_percentage: -40.72194,
        ath_date: "2021-04-14T11:54:46.763Z",
        atl: 51.3,
        atl_change_percentage: 62536.71794,
        atl_date: "2013-07-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        circulating_supply: 18719656,
        current_price: 32164,
        fully_diluted_valuation: 674764316483,
        high_24h: 33004,
        id: "bitcoin",
        image:
          "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
        last_updated: "2021-05-27T10:07:02.525Z",
        low_24h: 30652,
        market_cap: 601493137412,
        market_cap_change_24h: -15118857257.119507,
        market_cap_change_percentage_24h: -2.45192,
        market_cap_rank: 1,
        max_supply: 21000000,
        name: "Bitcoin",
        price_change_24h: -641.85835686,
        price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency: 0.25769270475453127,
        price_change_percentage_24h: -1.95655,
        price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency: -1.9565521832416402,
        price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency: 4.978932125496787,
        symbol: "btc",
        total_supply: 21000000,
        total_volume: 36947814578,
      },
    },
  },
};

let idx = 0; //key at index 0
let key = Object.keys(favourite.bitcoin)[idx];
console.log(key)
let data = favourite.bitcoin[key].data;
console.log(data)
```

Please let me know if it's works or not !

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But that did not work. I get "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(favorites.bitcoin)')". Anyways that solution is not suitable for me because there are many other coins that I want to iteration and I can't add each coin name to the code. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can also use coin name key's dynamic like above solution. and show me what you've tried so far now.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from your database, you need to query its parent reference. This will allow you to do things like "find all entries under `/favorites/bitcoin` that have a current price of over 30000".

Because you want to simply query for all the data under `/favorites/bitcoin` in your question, you would do the following:

1. Get a reference for `/favorites/bitcoin`
2. Get the data under `/favorites/bitcoin`
3. Iterate over the data, and assemble an array
4. Use this new array for your `FlatList`

These steps can be made into the following function:

```
function getDataForFlatlistUnder(databasePath) {
  return firebase.database()
    .ref(databasePath)
    // consider using .limitToFirst(10) or similar queries
    .once("value")
    .then((listSnapshot) => {
      // listSnapshot contains all the data under `${databasePath}`

      const arrayOfDataObjects = [];

      // For each entry under `listSnapshot`, pull its data into the array
      // Note: this is a DataSnapshot#forEach() NOT Array#forEach()
      listSnapshot.forEach((entrySnapshot) => {
        // entrySnapshot contains all the data under `${databasePath}/${entrySnapshot.key}`
      
        const data = entrySnapshot.child("data").val();
        // data is your data object
        // i.e. { ath, ath_change_percentage, ath_date, atl, ... }

        // add the key into the data for use with the FlatList
        data._key = entrySnapshot.key;

        arrayOfDataObjects.push(data);
      });

      return arrayOfDataObjects;
    });
}
```

Which you can use in your component like so:

```
function renderItem((dataObject) => {
  // TODO: render data in dataObject
});

function MyComponent() {
  const [listData, setListData] = useState();
  const [listDataError, setListDataError] = useState(null);
  const [listDataLoading, setListDataLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const disposed = false;

    getDataForFlatlistUnder("favorites/bitcoin")
      .then((arrayOfDataObjects) => {
        if (disposed) return; // component was removed already, do nothing

        setListData(arrayOfDataObjects);
        setListDataLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (disposed) return; // component was removed already, do nothing

        // optionally empty data: setListData([]);
        setListDataError(err);
        setListDataLoading(false);
      });

    // return a cleanup function to prevent the callbacks above
    // trying to update the state of a dead component
    return () => disposed = true;
  }, []); // <-- run this code once when component is mounted and dispose when unmounted

  if (listDataLoading)
    return null; // or show loading spinner/throbber/etc

  if (listDataError !== null) {
    return (
      <Text>
        {"Error: " + listDataError.message}
      </Text>
    );
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={listData}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item._key} // use the key we inserted earlier
    />
  );
}
```

**Note:** This code is for a one-off grab of the data, if you want realtime updates, you would modify it to use [`.on("value", callback)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on) instead. Make sure to use [`.off("value", callback)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#off) in the unsubscribe function of the `useEffect` call to clean it up properly.